# How to use an int from another class?

Tags: java, android

Im trying to use an integer, that Im using in one class and also use the SAME int in a different class.
I forgot, what do I have to do for that?

static? implements? extends? what?

Best regards,

For simplicity:

```
      public class ETBetaActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
      public static int anInt = 50;
```

Another class

```
            public class GUI extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
             public static int anInt_2 = 5+anInt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` is used to set that value to class, so all objects of the class will have that.

example:

```
  public class FirstClass
  {
      public static int yourInt;
  }
```

and you can access it like this: `FirstClass.yourInt`

You should consider the following example, if you want to avoid static:

```
public class FirstClass  
{
   private int yourInt;

   public getInt(){return this.yourInt;}
   public setInt(int _int){ this.yourInt = _int}
}
```

and from all the classes you can use this using getters and setters. Note that if you use 2nd method (with getter and setters ) you will have different values for `yourInt`, for each object you create, and that value should be set on constructor .

Comment: What do you mean public setInt(int _int){ this.yourInt = _int}? How will I use it in SecondClass?, Cause my int isn't static. It varies, that was an example.

Comment: For instance inside your SecondClass main you use it like this: First you create an instance of FirstClass object `FirstClass myFirstClassInstance = new FirstClass();` and after that you set the value for yourInt for new created instance like this: `myFirstClassInstance.setInt(50);`

Comment: Any idea why my app crashes? Trying to call this  public void results(){
  score.setText(classy.getResults());
 } ETBetaActivity classy = new ETBetaActivity(); and my ETBeta's results method:  public int getResults(){
  try {
  return (correct*5)/questions.length;
  } catch(Exception ex){
   return 1;
  }
 }

Comment: why are you catching Exception? Try to avoid catching that and use only certain exception classes. You don't need that try/catch block inside you function

Comment: Maybe your application crashes cuz correct == 0, and you try to return something like 0/int, and that is not correct

Comment: Yeah, it was 0.. when it shouldnt be 0! I have a tip.setText("Correct answers "+correct); which tells me it's > 0, when I'm correct. One sec, Ill show my whole code

Comment: Why does getResults() keeps returning me 0s? Even when tip.setText("..."+correct); says that it's > 0.

Comment: Not sure what causes it to do such a horrible thing to me.

Comment: Still waiting for that code snippet to track the error :). Maybe correct is changing it's value at some point and you don't notice it :)

Answer (score 1):

`ETBetaActivity.anInt`

```
public class GUI extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {              
public static int anInt_2 = 5+ETBetaActivity.anInt;
```

Or pass it by reference in some setting method in your GUI class.

Only use the first method listed above if those fields are going to be constant. =)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to implement or extend anything. If you are in the `GUI` class and want to access `ETBetaActivity`'s `anInt` field all you need to do is type:

```
public static int anInt_2 = 5 + ETBetaActivity.anInt;
```